# Passing regexes to prometheus query via grafana variables

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to pass custom variables to prometheus via grafana variables.

The values I've got setup in grafana are as follows:

- `.+` (as a custom `All` variable)
- `eu.+`
- `us.+`

The variables are used in a query such as:

```
some_metric{availability_zone=~"$az", ...}
```

The `All` variable works as expected, and the raw `eu-.+` values etc when put directly into the query also work fine - but when the variable is assigned via a dropdown, no metrics are returned. eg:

```
some_metric{availability_zone=~"eu.+", ...}
```

..correctly matches all metrics with labels such as `availability_zone="eu-west-1"`

[image: custom variable setup in grafana]

I've tried escaping and without in the custom values, but in for both of the custom values no metrics are returned.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this seems to be:

some_metric{availability_zone=~"${az:pipe}", ...}

The two "gotchas" being that you need regex comparison "=~" and the ${variable:pipe} to get the regex to run.

Comment: are you sure that you can apply regex to variables using ":" ?

Comment: This save me a lots of debugging. Thanks!

Comment: `=~"${variable:pipe}"`  instead of using ":", [ref](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#pipe) @smaiakov

Answer (score 0):

To make PromQL use regular expressions when matching labels, you have to use `=~` instead of `=`.

Your query should look something like this:

`some_metric{availability_zone=~"$az", ...}`

Comment: thanks for the answer - am already doing that, I'll update the example query.